# Typescript : Check if object exist in array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this data:

```
roles = [
{roleId: "69801", role: "ADMIN"}
{roleId: "69806", role: "SUPER_ADMIN"}
{roleId: "69805", role: "RB"}
{roleId: "69804", role: "PILOTE"}
{roleId: "69808", role: "VENDEUR"}
{roleId: "69807", role: "SUPER_RB"}
]
```

i have to filter my table to check if there is an object containing a specifie value of role .

My function should look like this :

```
checkRoleExistence(role){

// if role exists on one of the objects return true
// else returne false
}
```

to use it i would do s.th like this :

```
let ifExists = this.checkRoleExistence("PILOTE") ;
```

I would like to use the **"filter"** function of **Ecmascript** .

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: `My function should look like this` - it's empty? I don't think it should look like that at all - I think you need to put some code in there

Comment: @trichetriche but there's no need for filter and it's in french :(

Comment: You're the one asking for `filter`, I personally would have used `some`. And you can change the language !

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `some` method and *destructuring*.

```js
let roles = [ {roleId: "69801", role: "ADMIN"}, {roleId: "69806", role: "SUPER_ADMIN"}, {roleId: "69805", role: "RB"}, {roleId: "69804", role: "PILOTE"}, {roleId: "69808", role: "VENDEUR"}, {roleId: "69807", role: "SUPER_RB"} ]

const checkRoleExistence = roleParam => roles.some( ({role}) => role == roleParam)

console.log(checkRoleExistence("ADMIN"));
console.log(checkRoleExistence("RA"));
console.log(checkRoleExistence("RB"));
```

Comment: (upvoted) Or an ES6 one-liner : `const checkRoleExistence = roleParam => roles.some( ({role}) => role == roleParam)`

Comment: @SwapNeil, arrow functions are not supported in IE, you should use `babel` or just write a callback method for `some`.

Answer (score 7):

a little addition to all the answers given here. You can use find() to get value which matches your requirement.

`const index = this.roles.findIndex(role=> role.name === 'ADMIN');
if (index >-1) {
    const value= this.roles[index].roleId);
    }`

this will give you roleId , where it matches your query

Comment: The problem with that is that if `.find()` does not find the element, it returns `null`, and your script will crash with `Cannot read property 'roleId' of null`.

Comment: That's what the `if` statement is for
`if (index >-1)` then it found the element at the specified index. So it would never be null.

Answer (score 2):

I got this solution for you:
[check this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkroleexistence?file=src%2Fapp%2Frole%2Frole.component.ts)

```
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit {
  roles: Role[] = [];
  isRoleExist:boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = this.getRoles();
    this.roles = JSON.parse(data);

    this.isRoleExist = this.checkRoleExistence('PILOTE');
    console.log(this.isRoleExist);
  }

  checkRoleExistence(roleLabel: string):boolean {
    return this.roles.some(r => r.roleLabel === roleLabel);
  }

  getRoles() {
    return `[
    {"roleId": "69801", "roleLabel": "ADMIN"},
    {"roleId": "69806", "roleLabel": "SUPER_ADMIN"},
    {"roleId": "69805", "roleLabel": "RB"},
    {"roleId": "69804", "roleLabel": "PILOTE"},
    {"roleId": "69808", "roleLabel": "VENDEUR"},
    {"roleId": "69807", "roleLabel": "SUPER_RB"}
    ]`;
  }
}

export class Role {
  roleId: number;
  roleLabel: string;
}
```