# Check if array includes a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, and I need to prevent duplicate objects of being added to the array. I've tried the following code to check for duplicates:

```
const array = [{ name: 'John' }];

const newName = {
  name: 'John'
};
console.log(array);
console.log(newName);

if (array.includes(newName)) {
  console.log(newName.name + ' exists');
} else {
  console.log('name does not exist');
}
```

Console logging tells that the object NewName is exactly the same as array[0]. However,

```
if(array.includes(newName))
```

returns false.

What I'm I doing wrong? I tried the solutions in this post as well with no luck:

[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Arrays of Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e) and [Typescript : Check if object exist in array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498419)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `name` is the identity of the object, you can use `some` function on array:

```js
const array = [{ name: 'John' }];    
const newName = { name: 'John' };

if (array.some(({name}) => name === newName.name)) {
  console.log(newName.name + ' exists');
} else {
  console.log('name does not exist');
}
```

Or you can check if the count of properties is the same and then every property with:

```js
const array = [{ name: 'John', age: 33 }, { name: 'John', age: 45 }];    
const newName = { age: 33, name: 'John' };

if (array.some(x => Object.keys(x).length === Object.keys(newName).length && Object.keys(x).every(p => x[p] === newName[p]))) {
  console.log(newName.name + ' exists');
} else {
  console.log('name does not exist');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply, you can use `array.some` from 
[Array.prototype.some() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

In your own example, you can do some tweaks to your program:

```js
const array = [{ name: "John" }];

  const newName = {
    name: "John"
  };
  console.log(array);
  console.log(newName);

  if (array.some(object => object.name === newName.name)) {
    console.log(newName.name + " exists");
  } else {
    console.log("name does not exist");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing you're missing is that `includes` checks for *identity* when you use it on an object. `newName` has the same properties as the object in your array, but it isn't the same object any more than two people named John are the same person.  For a more obvious example, run `{} == {}` and you'll get `false`.

To check if the array contains an object with the same name, you can use `some` and pass it a function to compare the object, e.g.

```
array.some(e => e.name == newName.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

use it :

```
var newName = {
 name: 'John'
};
console.log(array);
console.log(newName.name);
var found = array.some(obj => obj.name === newName.name);

if (found) {
 console.log(newName.name + ' exists');
} else {
 console.log('name does not exist');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [{
  name: 'John'
}];

const newName = {
  name: 'John'
};

let resultArr = array.filter((item) => {
  return item.name === newName.name
})

let elementPresentMsg;

if (resultArr.length > 0) {
  elementPresentMsg = newName.name + ' exists';
} else {
  elementPresentMsg = 'name does not exist'
}

document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = elementPresentMsg;
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <p id="msg"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

If you want to find the name or any other value from array, if attributes of object are same as that in array of objects, the following should be helpful:

```
const array = [{ name: 'John' }];

const newName = {
  name: 'John'
};

let resultArr = array.filter((item) => {
    return item.name === newName.name
})

if (resultArr.length > 0) {
  alert(newName.name + ' exists'); //any way to print result instead of alert
} else {
  alert('name does not exist'); //any way to print result instead of alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to compare two different instances of objects which will never be equal.

But if you convert the objects to primitive strings by doing `JSON.stringify` you can then use `Array.includes` for deep comparison. As **ttulka** pointed out, this will only work if the object to be searched has the properties in the **same order** as the object to find in the array.

```js
const array = [{ name: 'John', age: 33 }];
const newName = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 33
};
if (array.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj)).includes(JSON.stringify(newName))) {
  console.log(newName.name + ' exists');
} else {
  console.log('name does not exist');
}
```

If you look into the [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) polyfill in MDN, you would see that the comparison happens using the `===` strict equality operator:

```
function sameValueZero(x, y) {
   return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
}

// 7. Repeat, while k < len
while (k < len) {
  // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
  // b. If SameValueZero(valueToFind, elementK) is true, return true.
  if (sameValueZero(o[k], valueToFind)) {
      return true;
  }
  // c. Increase k by 1. 
  k++;
}
```

So when you compare two different object literals using `===` they won't be equal:

```js
console.log({name :"John"} === {name :"John"});
```

But primitive strings on the other hand are equal if you compare them with `===`:

```js
console.log('{name:"John"}' === '{name:"John"}');
```

But the same is not true for String objects:

```js
console.log(new String('{name:"John"}') === new String('{name:"John"}'));
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't work for `const array = [{ name: 'John', age: 33 }]; const newName = {  age: 33,  name: 'John'};` even the objects are actually same.

Comment: No, you didn't ... change the order of properties... `JSON.stringify({ age: 33, name: 'John' }) !== JSON.stringify({ name: 'John', age: 33 })`

Comment: @ttulka yes if you change the order the, the output string from `JSON.stringify`  is different  so they won't be equal.

Comment: @ttulka I will update this observation in my answer, Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `array[0]` not equal `newName`. In Javascript, they point to the different element. You can try `console.log(array[0] == newName)`, and you will get `false`.
If you want to find the duplicates, you can try like this:

```
if (JSON.stringify(array).indexOf(JSON.stringify(newName)) != -1) {
  console.log('exist')
}
else {
  console.log('not exist')
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work generally because `JSON.stringify({ age: 33, name: 'John' }) !== JSON.stringify({ name: 'John', age: 33 })`

Comment: @ttulka I thought the input order is fixed, this is my fault.